# 'Some View' has no member 'bold'

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am getting the following error message when I add the Text modifier Bold;

[image: Xcode error message]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is a matter for SwiftUI. `.bold()` is modifier of `Text` so write `.bold()` modifier after `Text` statement.

Return type of `.padding()` and `.foregroundColor(.red)` is `View`.

```
Text("SomeText")
    .bold()
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.red)
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't render the text as bold.

Comment: @Stephen501 works fine. Please compare the text with and without bold. You can see the difference.

Comment: You can also use ```   .fontWeight(.bold)``` or ```.fontWeight(.heavy)```

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI 3 `.bold()` is a *modifier* of the font itself.

```
Text("Stephen Learmonth")
   .padding()
   .font(.title.bold())
   .foregroundColor(.white)
```

Comment: Thanks that's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I used the fontWeight(.bold) modifier immediately after the Text component. I am using SwiftUI 3.0 so I think that's why .bold isn't a member of Text()